# Looking for a word that means "pictures and videos"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means "pictures or video"/"pictures and video"? I was considering "media" but not sure if that would be correct.

For example, when discussing the smartphone app Snapchat, it becomes very repetitive to say things like "with Snapchat pictures and videos can be shared with friends".

Comment: Media or multimedia is fine.

Comment: @curiousdannii isn't *media* technically what the pictures or video travels through?

Comment: Like almost every word in every language, it has several meanings.

Comment: Please write a sentence where you should use this word!!

Comment: Your best bet is prolly just "images" and other than ugliness, what could be wrong with "stuff" or "things"?

Of course it would be repetitive to say things like "with Snapchat pictures and videos can be shared with friends" and could you drop both "with Snapchat…" and  "… can be shared with friends" and concentrate on the relevant "… pictures and videos…"?

Comment: If you can't share audio, media is overpromising. Not sure if you intended to limit or just gave examples.

Comment: If you want to name 2 things and exclude anything else, your best bet is to explicitly name the two things. You say "cats and dogs" if you want to talk about those two species, you don't look for a word like cat-dog or say "pet" and assume people know you don't mean rabbits or goldfish.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest "**visual media**". (See the 2005 collection of essays on literature and the visual media [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IeH9gNSag98C&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22visual%20media%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oM68VPLDPMLwaqe7gdAD&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22visual%20media%22&f=false).)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a title for your smart phone, try "Visual".
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the context given by the OP, I think **[imagery](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/imagery)** would be unambiguous. If the description needed tightening, that could be refined to '**visual imagery**'.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with the phrase 'Audio-Visual aids' but it mainly relates to audio + pictures.
However, possibly that would be of help as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Multimedia** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/multimedia)

> *adj.* 1.1 (Of computer applications) incorporating audio and video, especially interactively
> *"multimedia applications"*
>
> *noun* 1.1 An extension of hypertext allowing the provision of audio and video material cross-referenced to a computer text
> *"Many of our fellows also worked in the sphere of multimedia as well as computer games."*

Comment: It's important to add details to support an answer. See how I have done it for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about visual content. I think it is quite represent them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/431694)

Comment: Actually, it does provide an Answer, clear and simple.

That clear and simple is often not good enough for Stack Exchange is beside the point.

That it was poorly written and unsubstantiated is true, and would be irrelevant if SE understood axioms.

Answer (score 0):

**[pics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pic) & [vids](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vid)** is short and exactly matches the request if you don't mind that the expression is informal.

**media** would be an obvious choice when talking about online services like Snapchat except that it also includes audio and other things. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_media) says: "[...] This also includes text, audio, video, and graphics that are transmitted over the internet [...]."

**content** is another broad term often used to refer to things you watch or share online. Merriam-Webster: "[content](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/content) - the principal substance (such as written matter, illustrations, or music) offered by a website"

Answer (score -1):

I usually call these "Assets".

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the EL&U [help].